# Write a test class to test the following methods in the ​java.lang.String class:length ,charAt ,substring ,indexOf

Tags: java, junit

I have no idea how to write all those codes and then have them tested via the junit test. 
Obviously they require quite a few methods and such. But I am just at a loss for where to begin and what to do. Any help would be greatly welcomed.

Comment: Maybe ask the person who assigned this task to you to help.

Comment: @ScaryWombat if I could I would but they out of reach for time being.

Comment: For some examples that may be useful, take a look here: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-unit-testing/simple-test.html  and here: http://www.drjava.org/docs/user/ch07s02.html   Note that the first example seems particularly in line with your request, testing methods of the string class.

Comment: I see with question-asking being favored we are seeing more student assignment questions.  This one is a "where to even begin?"   Historically not a type of question that SO has been kind to. We've nearly all been there, and sometimes a small amount of guidance is all that's required. Will be interesting to see if SO can figure out a way to be friendlier on these, e.g., categorize them in a "new user help" area and have a way for answers to provide them with guidance, without doing the work for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and get this code running in a Java environment and editing some of the values to understand what it's doing.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Create a String to test with
        String testString = "some test text";

        // Prints out the number of characters in the String
        System.out.println(testString.length());

        // Prints out the character at the index of '2'
        System.out.println(testString.charAt(2));

        // Prints out a new String starting at index '5' and ending at index '9' 
        System.out.println(testString.substring(5, 9));

        // Prints out the index number that the word 'text' starts at
        System.out.println(testString.indexOf("text"));
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok, so what I learned from your code is, this basically all basic java. With different print methods for the testString. And depending on the values you set in the methods , will change the outputs.

Comment: Spot on mate, if you want to try experiment more, have a look at this site, it's very beginner friendly:
https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_strings.asp